# С чего начать писать на android?

Tags: android

Скажите, пожалуйста, с каких приложений лучше начинать писать новичку? Нужно написать свой будильник, калькулятор.

Или есть программы, проще с которых лучше начинать программировать на android? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Если с английским хорошо, рекомендую сайт [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/android). Если плохо, пошерстите описание к метке [Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info).

Comment: Если деньги есть - начните с фриланса в качестве заказчика. Будете заказывать программы, какие надо - в результате получите программы с исходниками, плюс объяснят вам да покажут. Из инструментов - рекомендую официальную Android Studio. Правда, если не планируете особых перспектив, то можно и Basic4Android какой-нибудь - но такие вещи сырые, часто глючат, при этом новичку с глюками не справиться.

Comment: Напишите - "здравствуй мир".

Comment: напиши таскер, в котором будет будильник, оповещения и подрузка каких-то данных из инета (картинки например)

Comment: Если знания не на уровне "привет мир", а немного более и хочется написать осмысленное приложение на котором и будешь повышать знания, я бы начал с простого блокнота.
В нем и списки будут и хранение данных, фрагменты , менюшки и с жизненным циклом придется пободаться. Приложение не сложное но много чего можно прикрутить .

Comment: Мой совет, бросайте теорию (ну, азы азов естественно нужны) и приступайте сразу к практике, гуглите на английском, найдете абсолютно все, в документацию не лезьте. Спустя какое-то время прочитайте книну от издательствa Head First по Java. А вообще на практике потихоньку и теорию можно познавать. Лично я так учился, проблем нет